# Identify different colors in an image using opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv

Sorry for the length of the question

```
 int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

 Mat image = imread(argv[1]);
 Mat blank(image.size(), CV_8U, Scalar(0xFF));
 Mat dest;
 imshow("originalimage", image);

 Mat markers(image.size(), CV_8U, Scalar(-1));
 markers(Rect (0, 0, image.cols, 5)) = Scalar::all(1);
 markers(Rect (0, image.rows-5, image.cols, 5)) = Scalar::all(1);
 markers(Rect (0, 0, 5, image.rows)) = Scalar::all(1);
 markers(Rect (image.cols-5, 0, 5, image.rows)) = Scalar::all(1);
 int centreW = image.cols/4;
 int centreH = image.rows/4;
 markers(Rect((image.cols/2)-(centreW/2),(image.rows/2)-(centreH/2), centreW, centreH)) = Scalar::all(2);
 markers.convertTo(markers,CV_BGR2GRAY);
 imshow("markers", markers);

 //Wateshed Segmentation
 WatershedSegmenter segmenter;
 segmenter.setMarkers(markers);
 Mat wshedMask = segmenter.process(image);
 Mat mask;
 convertScaleAbs(wshedMask, mask, 1, 0);
 double thresh = threshold(mask, mask, 1, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
 bitwise_and(image, image, dest, mask);
 dest.convertTo(dest,CV_8U);
 imshow("marker subtracted rgb dest",dest);

 Mat lab;
 cvtColor(dest,lab,CV_BGR2Lab);
 pre();
 imshow("cie lab image",lab);
 for(int i = 0;i < lab.rows;i++){
     for(int j = 0;j < lab.cols;j++){
         double l = lab.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0];
         double a = lab.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[1];
         double b = lab.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[2];

         if(!(l == 0 && a == 128 && b == 128)){//background color
             double dE1 = numeric_limits<double>::max();
             string result = "";
             node arg;arg.l = l;arg.a = a;arg.b = b;
             for(int k = 0;k < COLORS;k++){
                 double localE1 = CIE94(c_hash[k].value,arg);
                 if(localE1 < dE1){
                     dE1 = localE1;
                     result = c_hash[k].name;
                 }
             }
             cnt[result]++;
         }       
     }
 }
 unordered_map<string,int>::iterator it;
 int local_min = 0;
 string result = "NO Color! Something is fishy";
 for(it = cnt.begin();it != cnt.end();it++){
     if(it->second > 0)cout<<it->first<<endl;
     if(it->second > local_min){
         local_min = it->second;
         result = it->first;
     }
 }
 cout<<"maximum : "<<result<<endl;
 waitKey(0);
 return 0;
}
```

I'm first identifying my foreground object in the image and then converting dest image to cie lab color space. After that I have used CIE94 deltaE function to find the nearest standard color. But most of the time the answer is yellow, orange, red or magenta irrespective of what the actual color is. Can somebody tell me what's going wrong, thanks in advance.

Comment: Indentations please!!!!!!

Comment: @Arun A.S - I know it's a bit sketchy but could not indent it more. Hope u can understand the basic algo implemented

Comment: Can you provide sample images as well?

Answer (score 0):

A BGR image consists of three channels (Blue, Green, Red), yet you seem to think they are single channel images (having type CV_8U), e.g.:

```
Mat markers(image.size(), CV_8U, Scalar(-1));
...
markers.convertTo(markers,CV_BGR2GRAY);
...
dest.convertTo(dest,CV_8U);
....
cvtColor(dest,lab,CV_BGR2Lab)
```